# setting layouts visiblity on button click event

Tags: android, visibility, tablelayout, buttonclick

I am new to android and i am unable to solve my simple problem.I have a parent Tablelayout and inside it i have two tablelayouts with ids tbl1 and tbl2 respectively in my xml file.In tbl1 layout i have three textviews and three edittext controls similarly i have some views in tbl2 layout.Now i want that my tbl1 layout is visible when my activity starts but on click of my  button2 which is in tbl1 layout my tablelayout tbl1 gets invisible and my tablelayout tbl2 becomes visible.Actually i know i can achieve this in asp.net with the help of panels but in android i am not able to achieve the same thing.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look at the `setVisibility()` method. In the on click listeners for button 2, put the following;

```
Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
TextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
etc...
```

This will make the views invisible, but they will still take up space. If you don't want them to take up space you should use

```
setVisibility(Veiw.GONE);
```

Finally, to make you buttons and textview and edittexts in the second table, appear, you need to do the following;

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: you want to say that first of all i need to make all controls in layout1 invisible and then make them visible on click of the button

Comment: @rupinder18 Yes, you could do that in XML too if you wanted, with `android:visibility="gone"`

Comment: but then whats the use of placing different controls in different layouts...basically what i want is on click of a button particular group of controls becomes visible and on click of another button that particular group of controls becomes invisible and other group of controls becomes visible...like in asp.net we achieve this with the help of panels like i have panel1 and have some controls inside it then i set the visibilty of panel1 true on click of a button,the benefit of this is rather than setting the visibilty of each control we only set the visibility of a panel

Comment: @rupinder18 - instead of setting the visibility of each view units own you could set the visibiliy of the table row that each 'group' is in

Answer (score 0):

```
Java Code:
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.visibility_1);

        // Find the view whose visibility will change
        mVictim = findViewById(R.id.victim);

        // Find our buttons
        Button visibleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vis);
        Button invisibleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.invis);
        Button goneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gone);

        // Wire each button to a click listener
        visibleButton.setOnClickListener(mVisibleListener);
        invisibleButton.setOnClickListener(mInvisibleListener);
        goneButton.setOnClickListener(mGoneListener);
    }

    OnClickListener mVisibleListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mVictim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    OnClickListener mInvisibleListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mVictim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };

    OnClickListener mGoneListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mVictim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
}

XML Code:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/box"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:background="@drawable/red"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/visibility_1_view_1"/>

      <TextView android:id="@+id/victim"
          android:background="@drawable/green"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/visibility_1_view_2"/>

      <TextView
          android:background="@drawable/blue"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/visibility_1_view_3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/vis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/visibility_1_vis"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/invis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/visibility_1_invis"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/visibility_1_gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add explanation to your answer